# Creating a github repository

Tags: python, github, data-science

What am I missing here in the quick setup! This step is not in the help docs for creating a github repository...

In Google chrome, nothing happens when I click the button circled Red. Is the repository supposed to be created??

[image]

Comment: That button copies the text to your clipboard. Nothing else.

Comment: The icon itself shows a clipboard ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Click Set up in Desktop and do it in the Github Desktop [App](https://desktop.github.com)
- Copy the path and  do git clone in a command line like [this](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)